# Inline input-groups with wrapping if necessary

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'd like to put input-groups next to each other with dynamic width based on their contents. So far so good. My only problem is that they flow out of the container if they cannot fit in horizontally.

if space is enough:
[image]

if space is not enough (how it looks like now):

[image]

if space is not enough (how I want it):

[image]

The code I have:

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group mr-3 mb-2">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text">foo foo foo</span>
      </div>
      <select class="form-control custom-select">
        <option>baaaar</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group mr-3 mb-2">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text">foo foo foo</span>
      </div>
      <select class="form-control custom-select">
        <option>baaaar</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group mr-3 mb-2">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text">foo foo foo</span>
      </div>
      <select class="form-control custom-select">
        <option>baaaar</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're wrapping everything inside one `.form-group`. Each `input-group` should be within its own `.form-group`

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group mr-3 mb-2">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text">foo foo foo</span>
      </div>
      <select class="form-control custom-select">
        <option>baaaar</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group mr-3 mb-2">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text">foo foo foo</span>
      </div>
      <select class="form-control custom-select">
        <option>baaaar</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group mr-3 mb-2">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text">foo foo foo</span>
      </div>
      <select class="form-control custom-select">
        <option>baaaar</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```